# Text Alignment and Position on RTL site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

on my WordPress site i have plugin that add text into canvas to be added on product
the textarea itself work fine but when i click ok for the text to be uploaded into canvas it brakes
[image: text uploaded into canvas on RTL site with right alignment setting]

as you can see the text is out of the box with right text alignment settings
even if the text set to left alignment the output will be this

[image: text uploaded into canvas on RTL site with left alignment setting]

i think the alignment work but the position of the text is wrong

**if i set the website to be LTR like English language everything works fine**

first i thought it plugin issue but i create new server uploaded the plugin and its fully working with RTL LTR site with any alignment

So on my main site i disabled all plugins, cleared the Cash, remove all custom Css and Java and jQuery, delete database associated with canvas plugin, updated WordPress, changed the theme, checked on RTL.css on theme file editor and that didn't fix anything

is there anything im missing or anything i can check on or do

thanks for any help

Comment: Have you used your browsers devtools to see exactly what CSS is being applied and from where?

Comment: thank you for asking, i did, for the site i tried to change float and alignment and the canvas itself have no direct access to css of what inside it, the css only for the canvas itself like background color and these type of things also i tried to add css to canvas like text alignment but didn't work

Comment: OK, I misunderstood the question,it’s as it is being drawn onto an HTML canvas that it goes wrong,is that it? I see no way we can help without seeing the relevant code I’m afraid.

Comment: the most info i could get is from chrome recording feature for the textarea element inside the canvas with the issue 

type:change
target:main
selector:--

selector #1:
  body > textarea

selector #2:
  xpath//html/body/textarea

selector #3:
  pierce/body > textarea

value : 
  ABC aABCDE AB ABCDEFG

///////////
i recorded while i add a letter to the text that im facing the issue with, is that helpful AHaworth?